# Find coverage for plane from half-planes

Tags: computational-geometry, linear-programming

The document (see pic. below) states that it is possible to find a cover of the plane by a subset of 3 half-planes. It proposes to use linear programming for this. How to formulate such a program?

[image]

The original document can be found here: [On the Separation of a Polyhedron from Its Single-Part Mold](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.04203.pdf).

EDIT: For clarity: i need to understand how can i use LP to find subcoverage of size 3 from coverage of bigger size.

Comment: Have you looked at reference [10]?

Comment: What document is your image taken from? You should give credit to the authors, and provide a link to the original.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus looks like it is paywalled.

Comment: Sometimes there are free versions available on authors' websites.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus no luck, just want to clarify that i'm looking for proper formulation not linear LP algorithm, i have such.

Comment: Can you explain what you already know, and what you are looking for?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus i've edited the question, is that clear now?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the connection between Helly's theorem and linear programming
stems from this paper:

> Amenta, Nina. "Helly-type theorems and generalized linear programming." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 12, no. 3 (1994): 241-261.
>   ([Springer link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02574379).)

This arose from Nina Amenta's Ph.D. thesis ([PDF download](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~amenta/pubs/ninathesis.pdf)),
under the direction of Raimund Seidel.

Comment: thanks! very promising, hopefully i will have time to digest it. if i will find solution there i will accept your answer.